# How to make 3 divs side by side inside of 1 parent div and the width take up 75%of the page?

Tags: html, css

These are the instructions
1. Make a div, give it a class of 'feature_set_1_1'

2. Make a set of 3 divs inside the above div, sitting side by side, that together take up 75% of the width of the body
3. Add appropriate ids or classes to perform the following operations:

-Give your divs a set height

-Put 5% of space between the 1st and 2nd div via any method you wish

-Put 5% of space between the 2nd and 3rd div without further altering the 2nd div

-The three divs should all be on the same line, side by side

I must use class that assigned to parent div to make this and I can't find a way to make this work using class feature_set_1_1.

This is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Layout_1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
            .feature_set_1_1 {
                display: inline-flex;
                background: blue;
                width: 75%;
                height: 100px;
            }
            #1_1 {
                margin: 5%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #1_2 {
                margin-right: 5%;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #1_3 {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="feature_set_1_1">
            <div id="1_1">Figure1</div>
            <div id="1_2">Figure2</div>
            <div id="1_3">Figure3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following it may helps you.

```css
.feature_set_1_1 {
                display: inline-flex;
                background: green;
                width: 75%;
                height: 100px;
            }
            #div_1 {
                margin-right: 5px;
                width:25%;
                display: inline-block;
                background:yellow !important;
            }
            #div_2 {
                margin-right: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                width:25%;
                background:pink !important;
            }
            #div_3 {
                display: inline-block;
                width:25%;
                background:red !important;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Layout_1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="feature_set_1_1">
            <div id="div_1">Figure1</div>
            <div id="div_2">Figure2</div>
            <div id="div_3">Figure3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```